# setTimeout conflict in multiple instances of jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following small plugin which shifts class of `'focus'` between a set of elements.
This issue is, If I have multiple sets on a single page, with a new instance of the plugin applied to each set, there appears to be a conflict between the `setTimeout` function not staying within the plugin instance context.

```
(function($){

   $.fn.focusChanger = function(){

      return this.each(function(){

        //VARIABLES     
        var $this = $(this),
            $targets = $this.find('.focus-target'),
            numTargets = $targets.length,
            autoSpeed = 2500,
            autoChangeT = setTimeout(_autoChange, 500),
            currentIndex = numTargets;

        /////////////// Handlers ///////////////
        $this.hover(
            function () {
                //stop auto-changing
                _autoReset();
            },
            function () {
                autoChangeT = setTimeout(_autoChange, 500);
            }
        );


        /////////////// Functions ///////////////

        //Change Slide
        _changeFocus = function(newIndex){
            $targets.eq(currentIndex).removeClass("focus");
            $targets.eq(newIndex).addClass("focus");
            currentIndex = newIndex;
        };

        //auto slide changer
        function _autoChange() {
            console.log($this);
            var newIndex;
            if(currentIndex >= numTargets - 1){
               newIndex = 0;
            }else{
               newIndex = currentIndex + 1;
            };
            _changeFocus(newIndex);
            autoChangeT = setTimeout(_autoChange, autoSpeed);
        };
        // stop auto slide changer
        function _autoReset() {
            clearTimeout(autoChangeT);
            $targets.eq(currentIndex).removeClass("focus");
        };

      });//end each (plugin)

   };// end fn

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.fn.focusChanger){
        $('.focus-change-set').focusChanger();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Swpw2/8/

The above fiddle shows a working version of the plugin when applied to a single instance. Uncomment the second HTML block inside to see it break.

I have done my best to understand the following issue, but haven't been able to apply it to my plugin setup, as I am not passing `this` into the setTimout.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_%27this%27_problem
- [Pass correct "this" context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback)
- [jQuery plugin, context and setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587561/jquery-plugin-context-and-settimeout)

How can I keep the instances of the plugin (and I suspect `setTimeout` specifically) from interfering with each other?

Comment: You can actually store a timeout in jQuery's data() on each element seperately.

Comment: Are you able to show how that would work? or link to an applicable resource (http://api.jquery.com/data/ isn't much help)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
_changeFocus = function(newIndex){
```

to:

```
function _changeFocus (newIndex){
```

or:

```
var _changeFocus = function(newIndex){
```

Without the `var` or `function` keyword, you're declaring a global variable, so both instances are calling the same closure.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Swpw2/9/)

I figured this out by adding IDs to all the DIVs, setting breakpoints in the Javascript debugger. When I was in `_autoChange`, `$this` and `$targets` pointed to the first DIV. When I stepped into `_changeFocus`, they suddenly changed to point to the second DIV. That's when I noticed that you used different syntax to define these functions.

Comment: Doh. Amateur mistake, over-complexifying an issue down the wrong path! Thanks buddy.

Comment: If I had a dime for every question where the actual cause was totally different from what the OP was looking at....